# Appending function values to a list while iterating

Tags: python, list, numpy, append

I am a total Python newbie
so pardon me for this stupid question

The `composition()` function returns a certain value

However I only want the value to be `<=10`, and I want 100 of them
The code below calculates the times it took to simulate 100 `composition()` values to be of `<=10`

```
def find():
    i=1
    aaa=composition()
    while(aaa>10):
        aaa=composition()
        i=i+1        
    return i

Customers_num=[find() for i in range(100)]
Customers_num=np.array(Customers_num)
print(np.sum(Customers_num))
```

However, Suppose that the code above returns 150.
And I also want to know all the values that were being simulated in 150 times of `composition()`
What kind of code should I start with?

I am thinking about combining it with the `if else method statement` and appending the values to an empty list, but so far my code has been a total disaster

```
def find():
    i=1
    aaa=composition()
    bbb=[]
    if aaa<=10:
        bbb.appendd([aaa])
    else:
        bbb.append([aaa])
        aaa=composition()
        bbb.appendd([aaa])
        while(aaa>10):
            i=i+1
            if aaa>10:
                bbb.append([aaa])
            else:
                bbb.append([aaa])            
    return i,bbb

find()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could make a generator that will generate `n` of list of values from `composition()` and stop when `n` of them are `<=` 10. This list will include all the numbers, so you have all the intermediate values, and the length of this list will be how "long" it took to generate it. For example (with a fake random `composition()` function:

```
from random import randint

def composition():
    return randint(0, 20)


def getN(n):
    while n > 0:
        c = composition()
        if c < 10:
            n -= 1
        yield c

values = list(getN(10)) # get 10 values less than 10
# [2, 0, 11, 15, 12, 8, 16, 16, 2, 8, 10, 3, 14, 2, 9, 18, 6, 11, 1]

time = len(values)
# 19
```